# Is Time Series decomposition right approach?

Tags: time-series

I have sales data for last four year. I want to divide my data in two parts so that I can have  base volume and promotional volume. I am thinking to use " Decomposition of Time Series " approach such that the base volume would be trend component and seasonal and error component would be promotional volume.

Is this method would be good? 
Is there any other method/way to break down the data in two parts.

P.S : promotional volume is the volume that comes from promotions during festival seasons.

Answer (score 1):

Promotional volume that arises as a result of festival seasons is better to be handled by dummy variables. The error term is the reminder after trend, seasonality and such dummy.

Comment: Thanks for you reply...How to define dummy variables..can you please elaborate it more...it will be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: At times you know there were festival events that might have affected the series you put binary variable - 1 if there was a feast, 0 otherwise. Then you will perform regression with that variable included. It will estimate the impact of the festival event on the sales.

Comment: so you mean , the dependent variable would be my actual sales data and independent would be the the binary variables like you have defined and no other independent variables...Please reply as I like your approach... Thanks

Comment: of the form e.g.: y(t) ~ a + b*sin(2*pi*t/365) + c*cos(2*pi*t/365) + d*(IF festival at time t THEN 1 ELSE 0)

Comment: Why these sine and cos terms and why are you dividing by 365, I have monthly data for last 4 years...

Comment: would this model work : y(t) = d*(IF festival at time t THEN 1 ELSE 0) + e(t)

Comment: If you have monthly data then not 365 but 12 of course. However, you may not use sine+cosine if you don't expect waveform seasonality. The seasonality can be captured in the form of having m-1 independent binary variables for each month where m is number of seasons in a period, i.e. m=12. And additional term in the equation to capture festivals - the dummy variable.

Comment: If you don't need trend or seasonality, then the model reduces just to: y(t)~ a + d*(IF festival at time t THEN 1 ELSE 0) + e(t)

Comment: Thanks...This is will help..can you suggest me some books or site from where I can learn more about this...

Comment: YAFFEE, MCGEE: An Introduction to Time Series Analysis and Forecasting would be suitable for you, pitched math, even advanced time series concepts explained in a simple way